# How to call a constructor within its member function kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin-android-extensions

Following the Microsoft documentation, I would like to convert the following code from Java to Kotlin. However, Kotlin has init and constructor which I am not too sure on how do I implement it in my code. This is because I **need to call the constructor class in one of its member function.**

```
public class AzureServiceAdapter {
private String mMobileBackendUrl = "https://myappname.azurewebsites.net";
private Context mContext;
private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private static AzureServiceAdapter mInstance = null;

private AzureServiceAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mClient = new MobileServiceClient(mMobileBackendUrl, mContext);
}

public static void Initialize(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new AzureServiceAdapter(context);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialized");
    }
}
```

The above code is the Android Java code from Microsoft.

Referring to the code below, I was trying to convert the java code to kotlin. However, when I tried to be fancy and add in `init and constructor` to my kotlin code, I realised that I would get an error at `mInstance!!.AzureServiceAdapter(context) ?: throw IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialised")`

```
class AzureServiceAdapter{
private val mMobileBackendUrl = "https://test123.azurewebsites.net"
private lateinit var mContext: Context
private lateinit var azureClient: MobileServiceClient
var mInstance : AzureServiceAdapter? = null


private fun AzureServiceAdapter(context: Context){
    mContext = context
    azureClient = MobileServiceClient(mMobileBackendUrl, mContext)
}


fun initialize(context: Context) {
    mInstance!!.AzureServiceAdapter(context) ?: throw IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialised")
}
```

}

Hence, is there a way to convert Java code to kotlin in a professional structure?

Comment: SO you're making a singleton?  See the Kotlin documentation of how to do that here:  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html.  Its not the same as it is in Java.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan, I have read and tried to implement my code following that documentation but I still could not achieved the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for Convert java file to kotlin
```

Open Android Studio->Open Your project->Select your java file then
Go on Navigation Bar->**Code** **->** **Convert java file to kotlin file**

```
For this make sure your project is integrate with kotlin plugins
```